# tooltip and html problems?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

My codes are as follows. tooltip in `<del> </del>`  html tag not working why?
`<del>test</del>` test text with strikethrough does not appear.
What am I missing?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-html="true"
        title="<div class='col-12'><div class='row'><div class='col-4'>test</div><div class='col-4'><del>test</del></div><div class='col-4'>test</div></div></div>">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How does a code that looks so simple won't work :(

I reviewed the Bootstrap documents, but I can't understand it. It should work.

Comment: I just tested what you provided, and the tooltip appears. What is not working? Please be specific.

Comment: <del>test</del> test text with strikethrough does not appear. @terrymorse

Comment: Please add that detail to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: some of the OP's tooltip content is not showing, specifically the `<del>test</del>` section.

The reason: Bootstrap removes the `<del>` tag when displaying the tooltip.

Here is the HTML requested to be displayed:

```html
<div class='col-12'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-4'>test</div>
    <div class='col-4'>
      <del>test</del>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what Bootstrap displays:

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">test</div>
      <div class="col-4"></div>
      <div class="col-4">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why is Bootstrap stripping out tags?**

A review of Bootstrap's JavaScript code (tooltip.js & sanitizer.js) reveals that the code by default [sanitizes the HTML](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer) in Tooltips, permitting only those HTML elements that are in a whitelist. Here is that default whitelist of permitted tags:

```sh
<a>
<area>
<b>
<br>
<col>
<code>
<div>
<em>
<hr>
<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>
<i>
<img>
<li>
<ol>
<p>
<pre>
<s>
<small>
<span>
<sub>
<strong>
<u>
<ul>
```

In addition, only these element attributes are whitelisted:

```sh
all tags: class, dir, id, lang, role, aria-*
<a> only: target, href, title, rel
<img> only: src, srcset, alt, title, width, height
```

Everything else gets stripped out, but the sanitizer can be disabled completely with the following JavaScript:

```js
myElement.dataset.sanitize = false;
```

Bootstrap also documents a way to [add values to the default whitelist](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: When we use the `<s> test </s>` tag instead of the `<del> test </del>` tag, it works fine as strikethrough text.

Comment: You got lucky in using the `<s>` tag, as happens to be one of the few tags whitelisted by Bootstrap. See the update to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65942366/3113485), above.